# Is "\begin{align}" a legitimate tag?

Tags: mathjax

This block works well in MathJax

```
\begin{align}
a+b
\end{align}
```

and causes error in tex.

Is "\begin{align}" a legitimate tag? Do I need to import some package?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.